# Cant see action buttons on notification when app is in background

Tags: java, android, push-notification, action

I have added two actions to the notification i.e. accept and reject.
I can see both when the app is in foreground. But I cant see the actions when app is in background.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    private String mOrderId, mBillId;
    private Boolean mUpdateNotification;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.describeContents());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        //get data from server notification.


        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    }

    //send notification

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String title) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        long[] pattern = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500};
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.login_logo_1)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .addAction(R.string.accept,getString(R.string.accept), pendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.string.reject,getString(R.string.reject), pendingIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Also I want to handle the intents from these actions. For this I have created a class which extends broadcast receiver,but how to call this in an activity?

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String ACCEPT,REJECT;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(ACCEPT.equals(action)) {
                Log.v("Delivery","Accepted");
            }
            else if(REJECT.equals(action)) {
                Log.v("Delivery","Rejected");
            }

        }

}
```

Please help. Thank you..

Comment: same issue i am getting..

Answer (score 1):

In FCM there are three type of messages you can send

**1. Notification message**

> FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf
>   of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of
>   user-visible keys and an optional data payload of custom key-value
>   pairs.
>
> Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a
>   notification on your client app's behalf.

**2.Data message**

> Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages
>   have only custom key-value pairs.
>
> Use data messages when you want to process the messages on your
>   client app.

**3. Both Notification and Data**

> Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and
>   foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>   device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
>   of the intent of your launcher Activity.

[image]

So if you want to handle message on client side better you go with Data Message

[here you get all details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

**For send Data Message**

For Data Message you have to call post service using following URL

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

**Headers**

> Authorization:key=yourserverkey
>
> Content-Type: application/json

**Payload**

```
{"data": "extra data to be send",
 "to" : "devicetoken"
}
```

**Note: replace "to" with "registration_ids" : ["1","2","3","4","5","6"] for multiple devices**

In Application **onMessageReceived** you can get data message using **remoteMessage.getData()**

For detail already mentioned this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Here you also check to send notification to Topics using data message https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: I will send some data with it but how to handle this in an app? Can you please guide how to send data message for this and how I should handle it in an app? @Pavan

Comment: if you send data message along with notification it will not trigger onMessageReceived when app in in background as stated in table you have to send Data message only if you want to handle in app only the simple approach is edited in answer as i know further you have to search for same