# Not able to store data in SQLite or sharedpreferences when app is closed

Tags: android, sqlite, service, sharedpreferences, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried most of the solutions provided on SO. But, couldn't resolve this problem. 
The problem : When FCM notification arrives, i am starting service to store notification content into sqlite. Though it is working when app is open, it doesn't work when app is closed!!!

Here is my Service Class which I am using to store in sqlite. -->

```
public class NotiDataStoreService extends Service {

    DatabaseHelper db;
    String messageBody = "";

    public Runnable mRunnable = null;
    public NotiDataStoreService() {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                db = new DatabaseHelper(NotiDataStoreService.this);

                messageBody = intent.getStringExtra("messageBody");
                addNotification(messageBody);

                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("notification_details",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                int noti_counter = sharedPref.getInt("count",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("count", ++noti_counter).apply();
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void addNotification(String messageBody){
        File databaseFile = getDatabasePath(Constants.DATABASE_NAME);
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile,"", null);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("notification", messageBody);
        // Inserting Row
        Log.i("hexa:", "notification inserting locally");
        db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATIONS, null, values);
        db.close(); 
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks..! :)

Comment: which type of message you sending Data or notification check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484126/cant-see-action-buttons-on-notification-when-app-is-in-background/44484918#comment75965714_44484918

Comment: It is notification. and there is no issue in receiving notification. :)

Comment: FCM has two type of notification Data and Notification where in case  of Notification message it will not invoke onMessageReceived when app is in background so it matter bro :)  check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Oh okay, My bad. But, you can assume that onMessageRecieved is called every time. Because i have checked via debugging.

Comment: when app is in foreground then it will but not in background FCM automatically manage to show it

Comment: Yeah, that might be the issue. Can you suggest alternative for that or how should i store notification messagebody in sqlite when app is in background? Thanks :)

Comment: if you want this then go with data message which will be completely handled at client side it will invoke onMessageRecieved in both foreground and background state here which i know more you have to search on it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484126/cant-see-action-buttons-on-notification-when-app-is-in-background/44484918#comment75965714_44484918

Comment: @Pavan thanks a ton!! Yeah, it was the problem. I changed to "Data" carrier in notification and it worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From FCM [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

To receive messages, use a service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService`. Your service should override the `onMessageReceived` and `onDeletedMessages` callbacks. It should handle any message within `10 seconds` of receipt. After that, Android does not guarantee execution, and could terminate your process at any time. If your app needs more time to process a message, use the Firebase Job Dispatcher.

`onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:

> `Notification` messages delivered when your `app` is in the
>   `background`. In this case, the `notification` is delivered to the
>   device’s `system tray`. A user tap on a `notification` opens the app
>   launcher by default.
>
> `Messages` with both `notification` and `data` payload, both
>   `background` and `foreground`. In this case, the `notification` is
>   delivered to the device’s `system tray`, and the `data` payload is
>   delivered in the `extras` of the `intent` of your launcher Activity.

**In summary:**

```
App state    | Notification       | Data               | Both
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Foreground   | onMessageReceived  | onMessageReceived  | onMessageReceived
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Background   | System tray        | onMessageReceived  | Notification: system tray
                                                         Data: in extras of the intent.
```

**SOLUTION:**

From the above guideline, it seems that client app receives a `data` message in `onMessageReceived()` both `foreground` and `background` state. So, If you want
to handle your message both `foreground` and `background` state, then you should send push message with `data` payload.

Here is a good tutorial about FCM (`Notification` and `Data payload`):

[Android Push Notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging FCM & PHP](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks a lot , Mate! It worked.i changed to data in message and it worked like charm :D.